# WKHTMLTOPDF works on command line, but returns 0 byte pdf when generating from PHP

Tags: php, pdf, centos, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using WKHTMLTOPDF to generate PDFs. It's been working fine but we've recently changed server and it's now only giving us back 0 byte files from our PHP admin panel.

Strangely, if I run the below from ssh, it generates just fine. I guess it's perhaps an issue with permissions of www-data but I can't figure it out :(

WKHTMLTOPDF is at /usr/local/bin/wkhmtltopdf and we're using httpd and centos.

If more info is needed I'm happy to try provide it. I can't seem to find any log for wkhtmltopdf either, it doesn't go into the httpd log.

Appreciate the help! Pulling my hair out :p

EDIT: here's the code I'm using to generate the PDF - it has worked on the old server

```
PDF::setOutputMode('F'); // force to file

    PDF::setPageSize('a0');

    $gen = PDF::html('pdf.print.web', [
        'products' => $catalogue,
        'name' => $master->name
    ], storage_path()."/pdf/gen-".$master->url);

    return Response::download(storage_path()."/pdf/gen-".$master->url.'.pdf');
```

Comment: Does it send any output to standard output or standard error? Are you capturing that output?

Comment: How are you executing it, `passthru` maybe? Try executing some shell commands such as `ls -la /usr/local/bin/wkhmltopdf` and `id`.

Comment: Sorry! Guess I should mention I'm using https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf from PHP. I'm not sure of any output - nothing is getting logged, it just returns 0 byte pdf :(

Comment: Can you provide the code that's generating the pdf?

Comment: I've updated the OP with the code generating the PDF. It's worth mentioning that this worked perfectly on the old server :(

Comment: What everyone is asking for: put `var_dump($stdout,  $stderr, $rtn);die();` between lines 986 and 987 (assuming you're on master branch and not changed the lib) of src/Nitmedia/Wkhtml2pdf/Wkhtml2pdf.php file of the library you're using. And update your question with the output

Answer (score 0):

A had a similar issue using wkhtmltopdf CLI (not PHP). It ended up being a permission issue.

When I did:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

The operation would succeed but generate a 0-byte pdf. No errors thrown.

When I did:

```
sudo wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

The pdf has content. So ensure the relevant user(s) have r/w/e permission to the command itself and to the location where you want to write the file. Also make sure they have permission to make the outbound web request if relevant, and the server is config'd to allow this. You won't actually have to sudo once the permissions are fixed.

Hope this helps.